# How can I view web pages in a browser tab INSIDE Visual Studio 2010 with CHROME?

Tags: visual-studio, google-chrome, browser

I'm not talking about launching an external browser with "browse with".
I want to pull up a random web page in a browser window INSIDE VS2010,
but use CHROME instead of IE to render the web page.
I'm just so completely done with IE. Thanks!

I'd consider a VS IDE add-on or add-in or extension or whatever they are calling it nowadays,
and I'll entertain building one with Chromium if there's enough demand,
but I dont' want to have to do that...
thanks!

Comment: I think a third-party extension is likely your only option here, as there's no way to configure VS to use a different browser internally.

Comment: An extension is definitely possible, since all designers in Visual Studio are simply programs running inside a window. where that window is docked is easily controlled (can be docked in main tab control).